# Remove all text within specific tags

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace, strip

I am interesting in removing all the text within the following tags:

```
<p class="wp-caption-text">Remove this text</p>
```

Can anybody give me an idea of how this can be done in php?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you want to keep the tag and remove the text or remove the whole element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex - Grab a specific word within specific tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332619/regex-grab-a-specific-word-within-specific-tags) and a at least a few dozen more. Use [a DOM parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662) and the solution is the same for any "Fetch text content for `<whatever>`"

Comment: I am actually not a fan of any of these answers to be completely honest.  While good patches they are not solutions by any means.  The only real solution is going through the code and removing the places that generate this content to begin with.  Otherwise you have one process waisting time creating content and one wasting time removing content.

Comment: @Geoffrey that's true but we do not know if the OP has control over the generating code. S/he might be scraping someone's blog.

Comment: @Gordon And that is exactly why i answered the question below with a regexp because it answers the OP

Comment: @Geoffrey that still doesnt make the question less of a duplicate though. In fact, answering duplicates is discouraged. It clutters the place.

Comment: @Gordon what you see as clutter, i see as affirmation to a point.  The more times that someone phrases the same question differently the more likely someone is to google for something and get a match.  Especially if they are asking very basic regex questions meaning they have very little programming background in the area of string manipulation.

Comment: @Geoffrey No. This has been discussed ad nauseam. [The general concensus](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions) is that some duplicates are good to cover variation but covering every possible variation isn't. There is at least one question daily asking "how to extraxt x from html". This is completely superfluous because all these questions basically ask the same thing. It doesnt matter if the element is foo or bar, nor does it matter if the class is wp_foo or xy_bar. These are completely irrelevant details for the solution.

Comment: @Gordon and the solution is what? http://www.google.com?q=remove+thing+from+string+because+i+dont+know+how+to+phrase+it Seems silly to flame a person (which is how i am currently perceiving your side of the argument here) because they dont know a term.  Just because something is discussed at great length doesn't mean it is right.  I am sure a large group of people with important titles discussed the (reference to an exploding like device dropped over japan that stack overflow filters out of comments) at great length as well.

Comment: @Geoffrey You are assuming people are dumb, but they are just lazy. The OP was smart enough to ask a rather general question with "remove all text within specific tags". If you enter that as a question, SO will suggest possible duplicates already on the input form. If the OP had taken the time to go through these (as is encouraged by the forced [Ask Advice page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice)), s/he'd learned the proper terms and background information and eventually would have been able to solve this question from what is already there.

Comment: @Geoffrey moreover, even if the gazillion duplicates wouldn't have helped the OP, it is still better to closevote/not answer this question and point the OP to an existing appropriate question that deals with the problem on a higher level or is similar enough to solve the issue. That'd still leave the question findable in Google, but direct to a more canonical and hopefully more complete solution. You only threw the OP a fish. S/he'll c&p it and learn nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the tag and content inside of it:

```
 $content = preg_replace('/<p\sclass=\"wp\-caption\-text\">[^<]+<\/p>/i', '', $content);
```

or if you want to preserve the tags:

```
 $content = preg_replace('/(<p\sclass=\"wp\-caption\-text\">)[^<]+(<\/p>)/i', '$1$2', $content);
```

Answer (score 2):

As bit higher-level alternative to regular expressions.

You can process with DOM. You can match all nodes you're looking for with XPath `//p[@class="wp-caption-text"]`.

For example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($yourHTMLasString);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = '//p[@class="wp-caption-text"]';
$entries = $xpath->query($query);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $entry->textContent = '';
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: I really like this solution too.  Just remember that both this and regexp have a large amount of overhead as the document size grows. I would recommend only doing these operations once and saving the output to a cache to be reserved without processing.

Comment: @Geofferey: true, for very large files I'd recommend rewriting above logic to XSLT and running it with SAX XSLT processor.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$string = '<p class="wp-caption-text">Remove this text</p>'; 
$pattern = '/(.*<p .*>).*(<\/p>.*)/'; 
$replacement = '$1$2'; 
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: This REGEXP will not work if the string is an entire web page.  Your .* between your p tags will grab as much as it can for the entire page until it finds the very last p on the page.

Answer (score 0):

if its always the same tag you could simply do search for the string. use the position resulting to substring from it to the closing tag.
Or you could use a regular expression, there are good ones posted here that can help you.

Comment: Can you please provide example code of how I could do this, as I am very inexperienced with php